# eCobertura and dbunit don't find persistence.xml for tests

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, code-coverage, cobertura, ecobertura

I have a couple of dbunit-tests for a jee5-project. They work great when I try to run them with "run as TestNG test" in Eclipse. But when I try to run them as "Cover as TestNG test" they fails with the error `"javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named test".`

To me it seems like the "Cover as.." attempt to run the tests with the wrong persistence.xml, eg not using the one in src/test/resources/META-INF but rather src/main/resources/META-INF (or no one at all).

Is there a way to tell cobertura that it needs the files in src/test/resources to run the tests?

Should I report a bug to the eCobertura-developers?

Comment: Reporting a bug might be best option, can you give a full stack trace?

Comment: there is old bug: http://cobertura.996293.n3.nabble.com/Cobertura-is-not-using-persistecnce-xml-from-test-classes-td1125.html

Comment: I would log this to the cobertura issues page: https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues